# Can it hurt me to accept a brief "Visiting Lecturer" position?

Tags: career-path, job-search

I must make a difficult decision, so am having to turn to the wider community to gain some perspective.

My situation is the following: I am currently outside USA and am trying to enter academia here. I have been invited as a visiting lecturer at a top US university. However, I am worried that though certainly valuable, a purely teaching position might be a huge negative against me in terms of prospects for a more research oriented position (Asst or Assoc Prof). Or is my trepidation unjustified?

Comment: **I say it's a plus.** Top US universities don't invite "anyone" as a guest lecturer.

Comment: Perhaps you need to ask yourself why you do want to take it?

Comment: You haven't told us what your field is.  In my field (mathematics), most new PhDs work as visiting assistant professors or postdocs for several years before their first tenure track position.  Starting off as a visiting assistant professor is not particularly unusual or a bad thing in this field.

Comment: Another important issue is what kind of visa the employer is willing to sponsor you for.

Answer (score 11):

The title of *lecturer* does not necessarily imply that you would teach full time. Sure, it usually implies more teaching than research, but that does not mean it's strictly teaching only. Especially for a visiting lecturer position, one could imagine there be arrangements possible.

So: have you checked the exact term under which you would be employed?

Also: how long would be this “brief” position? And what is your current seniority in your local research system? Those factors will play heavily into the decision.

Overall, I expect it's a net positive for you if you manage to keep some research activity going on, especially if you can travel relatively often to visit your non-US lab. Otherwise, if it's purely teaching with no opportunity to maintain some research activity, and you are not far from getting a job where you are, accepting might be risky.

*“Long absent, soon forgotten”*

Comment: Thanks for your useful advice. It is just for a single course so I should have time to research and network. And the position would be at most 2 semesters. Also I finished a Phd in 2008, so am no longer an introductory level candidat...

Comment: Okay, in these circumstances, and unless you have a very specific opportunity for employment in your current country in the year to come, it seems that accepting the position would be a smart move.

Answer (score 5):

These days, I believe having experience in foreign countries is considered a plus almost everywhere. Even if you're strictly speaking in a teaching-only position, that doesn't mean you can't take advantage of that to do some research "on the side," and to make contacts with researchers at the university where you're teaching, and at other schools in the vicinity. You might also have an opportunity for more networking.

The only way this is a real negative is if you're in such a period for an extended period of time (say, on the order of several years), and then want to pivot back to a research focused career. Then you will have to overcome the challenge of proving that you'll be able to raise enough money to sustain a research group. Beyond that, however, I can't see any real downside to a short (one year?) appointment. I think if the choice is between that and being unemployed, the job is definitely the better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedbak. Perhaps you are right I can take advantage of research "on the side".